# OrderBy Observable collection in Descending order - UWP

Tags: c#, sorting, uwp, observablecollection

I can order by my observable collection using below code. How can I order by it in descending order?

```
  RollNoArray _mainItems = new  RollNoArray();
  _mainItems.SubItemsList = new ObservableCollection<SubItems>();
  //..adding data to _mainItems.SubItemsList here
  _mainItems.SubItemsList = new ObservableCollection<SubItems>
 (from i in _mainItems.SubItemsList orderby i.num select i);// order by num
```

Comment: from i in _mainItems.SubItemsList orderby i.num `descending` select i

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq **OrderByDescending** instead of OrderBy:

```
_mainItems.SubItemsList.OrderByDescending(i => i.num).ToList();
```